# How to plot an n-points discrete segment between two given points in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

Given two points, what's the best way to plot - in Matlab - a n-points discrete segment that has these points as extremes?
What if I have to plot a chain of discrete segments like that?

Thank you in advance!

The following is an example of what I'm trying to achieve in the easiest possible way
[image: An example]

Comment: You mean a straight line?

Comment: Yes, a discrete segment between two points!

Comment: so... you tried to use `plot`?? Your question is extremely unclear. Please provide some sample inputs and manually draw the output plot you are after. Also include some code to show that you have tried to solve it yourself

Comment: Yes but I'm supposing I don't know the "equation" of the line on which the segment lies but just the extrem points and the spacing between discrete points of the segment. Is there an easy way of doing this with plot?

Comment: plot will connect the dots by default...

Comment: I don't know the coordinates of all the dots! Let's say I want to plot the triangular plot between the points (35,0) - (40,0.2) - (45,0) and all I know are these points and the fact that I want the dots to be spaced of unity!

Comment: I added a picture in the question Dan! I don't know if my question is incredibly silly still...I wasn't able to find anything by googling!

Comment: You can use `linspace` to generate the points with equal distance and then `interp1` for the interpolation between the boundary points. Check out both functions in the Matlab help.

Comment: Use plot.... The figure you posted has to have been created using `plot(x,y,'o')` or `scatter(x,y)`. Use `plot(x,y)`

Comment: As an alternative, use the `colon` operator instead of `linspace` to generate the values for the x-axis.

Comment: How do I choose the spacing between points in plot or scatter Ander? I'm supposing I don't know the equation of the line (hence of the segment) but only the extreme points

Comment: Nemesis I'm trying what you're suggesting. Something like:
x=linspace(35,40,6);
y=linspace(0,0.2,6);
plot(x, y,'ko');
But how to "append" in a clever way the other segment, the descending one? In the end, I need to have only one x-vector and one y-vector because I'd have to renormalize it! (Indeed, this would be a discrete probability distribution)

Comment: @luciadefinetti you still need to add your actual input vectors, the actual data

Comment: @Dan My actual data are the 3 points (35,0) - (40,0.2) - (45,0) and the fact that I want them connected by discrete unity-spaced-dots segment.

Comment: Abd what does "unity-spaced" mean? Euclidean distance? Distance in the x direction?

Comment: Yes @Dan, x-direction.

Comment: @luciadefinetti then hbaderts solution answers your question. In future when asking question please include all the necessary information upfront

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dan :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your points are stored in the fashion `p = [35,0; 40,0.2; 45,0]`, i.e.

```
p =
   35.0000         0
   40.0000    0.2000
   45.0000         0
```

Then you can create an array for all `x` values by finding the mininum and maximum values of the x coordinate. Here, the x coordinate is the first column of `p`, i.e. `p(:,1)`. You can use the [colon operator `:`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) to create the `x` array by

```
x = min(p(:,1)) : 1 : max(p(:,1))
```

The `1` in the middle is the step width. For your example, this will create the array

```
x =
    35    36    37    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45
```

Now you can interpolate all `y` value linearly with the [`interp1`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function. This does a linear interpolation by default. The syntax is thus

```
y = interp1(p(:,1), p(:,2), x)
```

Finally you can plot the vectors `x` and `y` using [`plot`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). If you only want to print circles, use `'o'` as LineSpec specifier. To connect the circles using a line, use `'-o'`. There's an extensive list of options [here](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_LineSpec). You can also add the color of the line / markers to this format spec. Black circles would be `'ok'`:

```
plot(x, y, 'ok')
```

[image: result]

Comment: beautifully presented answer :D

Comment: Thank you very very much @hbaderts

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your project. @Adriaan my mistake, see edited answer ;)

Comment: I'm proud of the few things I am able to do right know and, among them, selecting colours for the dots fills me with joy :)